# multiprocessing in IPython console on Windows machine - if __name_ requirement

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, ipython

I'm working with IPython and Spyder IDE on a Windows machine. When the IDE is starting, a set of py-files is loaded to define some functions that make my work a bit easier. Everything works as expected.

Now I would like to upgrade one of these function to use multiprocessing, but on Windows this requires the `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement. So it seems that I cannot call the function directly and pass the arguments from the IPython console.

For example one of the py-files (let's call it test.py) could look like the following code.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import string

# define a example function
def rand_string(length, output):
    """ Generates a random string of numbers, lower- and uppercase chars. """
    rand_str = ''.join(random.choice(
                string.ascii_lowercase
                + string.ascii_uppercase
                + string.digits)
           for i in range(length))
    output.put(rand_str)


def myFunction():
    # Define an output queue
    output = mp.Queue()        

    # Setup a list of processes that we want to run
    processes = [mp.Process(target=rand_string, args=(5, output)) for x in range(4)]

    # Run processes
    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    # Exit the completed processes
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    # Get process results from the output queue
    results = [output.get() for p in processes]

    print(results)
```

In my IPython console I would like to use the line

```
myFunction()
```

to trigger all the calculations. But on Windows a end up getting a BrokenPipe error.

When I put

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     myFunction()
```

at the end of the py-file and run the complete file by

```
runfile(test.py)
```

it works. Of course. But that makes it very hard to pass arguments to the function as I always have to edit the test.py-file itself.

### My question is: How do I get the multiprocessing function running without putting it in this `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement??

Comment: Did you try `import test` and then calling `test.myFunction()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I solved that specific problem.

1. Put the defintion of `rand_string` in a separate file, called
   `test2`.
2. Import `test2` as module into my `test.py` script

   `import test2 as test2`
3. modify the following line to access the `test2` module

   ```
   processes = [mp.Process(target=test2.rand_string, args=(5, output)) for x in range(4)]
   ```
4. Run `test.py`
5. Call `myFunction()`
6. Be Happy :)

The solution is based on this [multiprocessing tutorial](http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html#importable-target-functions) that suggests to import the target function from another script. This solution bypasses the safe self import by the `if __name__` -wrapper to get access to the target function.

Answer (score 3):

`multiprocessing` doesn't work without running with `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

You could however, use a fork of `multiprocessing` that essentially leverages `dill` to treat the interpreter session as a file… (in short, it works).

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 11 2014, 01:21:43) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool

In [2]: def squared(x):
   ...:     return x**2
   ...: 

In [3]: x = range(10)

In [4]: p = Pool()

In [5]: p.map(squared, x)
Out[5]: [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]

In [6]: res = p.imap(squared, x)

In [7]: list(res)
Out[7]: [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]

In [8]:
```

You can use the built-in `multiprocessing` that's been augmented by the `dill` serializer too, or you can build a `Queue` with `Pool().apipe`, either of which are more like what you seem to be interested in doing with `Queue`.

Get pathos here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Comment: It seems worth a try, but I am using Python 3.4 which is currently not supported by pathos. Maybe in two month, when the next version will be released that also supports Windows.

Comment: The `pathos` master/trunk now supports windows, but is still `2.x`-only.  It should work on `3.x` shortly, however.  The core of `pathos.multiprocessing` is now in a standalone package called `multiprocess` that works on `2.x` and `3.x`, and also supports Windows.