# Code gets hung when using multiprocessing

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, ipython-parallel

I want to run a simple function across seperate cores on my computer.  My computer has four cores.

To start with, a simple function:

```
def exp(x):

    return x**2
```

now I want to give this function four separate numbers, and use a different core to apply the function so that the calculations are done in parallel.

I am trying like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    check = [1, 5, 6, 8]
    pool = mp.Pool( mp.cpu_count())
    results = pool.map(exp, check)
```

but this seems to execute and then it gets hung up, so I am not sure I am using pool correctly here.

I also tried this:

```
results = [pool.apply_async(cube, args=(x,)) for x in range(1,7)]
output = [p.get() for p in results]
```

but it gets hung on the last line again.

I am using ipython in ancondas spyder environment, this could also be why? Maybe I need to use ipythons parallel?

EDIT:

The answer to my problem was found here, [multiprocessing in IPython console on Windows machine - if __name_ requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630217/multiprocessing-in-ipython-console-on-windows-machine-if-name-requirement)

Comment: Can't repro. Works for me. What OS are you on?

Comment: hmmm, I'm on Windows 7