# Failed to create sub-process in Python on Windows 10

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I found the code below on the python website.

However the code does not compile on Windows 10 with Python 3.6.5 installed.

I've tried the same code on Ubuntu 16.04 (Python 2.7) and the code works fine.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print ('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

The error I get is shown below. I've only shown the last line of the stack trace since this seems to be where the error is generated. I've done a lot searching but have not found a solution.

> File "J:\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\context.py",
>   line 321, in _Popen
>       from .popen_spawn_win32 import Popen
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'Popen'

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Maybe this can help  ==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630217/multiprocessing-in-ipython-console-on-windows-machine-if-name-requirement

Comment: Tried that, no success. It may be that it's not possible to create processes on windows.

Comment: I saw that people manage to create process using OS library. But your questions mentions the multiprocessing one. Did not answer that since that was not the question.  But this solution might be helpful none the less : https://github.com/celery/billiard/issues/70

Comment: Yes I'll use the OS library. Thanks.