# How can I print a string when using the multiproccessing module?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, multiprocessing

I post this small reproducible example of the issue I'm trying to solve. I'm using the multiproccessing python module and I want to print a string on the console, but nothing appears. If you execute the function without multiprocessing is working though.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def print_works(a):
    print(f"it works {a}")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    l=[1,2,3]
    p = mp.Pool(processes=1)
    p.map(print_works, l)
    p.close()
```

The result I want to obtain is:

```
it works 1
it works 2
it works 3
```

If you execute the function in a for loop it works:

```
l=[1,2,3]
for i in l:
    print_works(i)
```

The result is the one I want to obtain:

```
it works 1
it works 2
it works 3
```

**Note:** This is a silly example of the functionality I want to implement. I'm using Python 3.6.8, Windows 10 and VS Code editor.

Comment: Your code works as expected for me. Python 3.8.3, Arch Linux. Note however, that the order of the prints is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response  @attalos. The order doesn't matter in this case. It's curious, if I execute it on the terminal is working. It seems only failing on the IPython console of VS Code. Do you know what could be happening?

Comment: Take it look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630217/multiprocessing-in-ipython-console-on-windows-machine-if-name-requirement

Comment: Do you have to use the IPython console in VS Code? It seems a bit unreasonable for a parallel application. When I execute it normally (python3 file.py), also in VS Code, it works fine.

Comment: You're right I can use he console. I was just wondering why is not working in the IPython console.